# Expanding multiple textareas with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, expand

Im new with JQuery or Javascript, but I dont know why ,only one of my textarea expands, but other not. I found this code, but I dont know, how to fix this problem. You can test this in my **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/vLh1ysyq/)**

There is the JQuery

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('.text1, .text2');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', autosize);

function autosize(){
  var el = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.cssText = 'height:auto; padding:0';
    el.style.cssText = 'height:' + el.scrollHeight + 'px';
  },0);
}
```

Comment: [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns the **first** matched element

Comment: note: this is a pure javascript, not jQuery. And why you use setTimeout() ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f0c8oz70/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a list of elements and then iterate to bind the event handler.

```
var textarea = document.querySelectorAll('.text1, .text2');
for (var i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
  textarea[i].addEventListener('keydown', autosize);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0c8oz70/)